# Why is Tension = Friction here?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, friction

I was going through this question :-

> [image]

In the answer it says :

> If there would be no friction between monkey and the rope, the monkey will slide down the ground. **It is the frictional force which take him in upward direction.**

But my question is that , the monkey  is accelerating upwards with an acceleration a, so the monkey has a **tendency of slipping upwards**, so the friction must act downwards and so the resultant FBD must be something  like this:

> [image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The hands of the monkey do a downward force in the rope. The reaction of the rope does a force on the monkey upwards. If this force is greater than $g$, it (its centre of mass) accelerates.

Comment: Um could you explain why my approach is wrong?

Comment: There would be a friction force downwards if the hands of the monkey were sliding upwards. But it is not the case.

Comment: Forget the tension T. If the monkey is stationary  then f - mg = 0. If the monkey moves up then f - mg = ma or f = m (g + a).

Comment: .... since the rope doesn't move  then f-T = 0 or T = f in both static and moving case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the monkey can never have a tendency of 'slipping upwards' in any real-world phenomenon that doesn't discount the effects of gravity (which is quite significant in all such cases and cannot be neglected).

The normal contact force acts normally to the monkey's climbing hands at all times, opposing its upward motion, enabling it to climb upwards. Note that I didn't say it is directed upwards, just that it opposes this upward motion of the monkey, without which it would slip and fall.

Tension is the force acting upwards, equal(in the static situation, for a body to move upwards, tension must exceed the opposing frictional forces) and opposite to the weight of the body(the monkey). This can be equated to the frictional force acting at that point. Think of tension as an intrinsic characteristic of the rope, that expresses itself as friction, a parallel contact force.

Hope this helps clarify!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

There should not be any tension in your free body diagram of the monkey. Friction acts upwards because friction opposes relative motion between objects. The monkey's hands would slide down the rope if there were no friction, so friction opposes that by pushing upwards.